# mark all inputs as a required not working with ngFor

Tags: angular

I want all inputs to be required and enable the button just if the user fill all the inputs.
but now when the user fill just the first one the button enabled.

here is the [Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/mbMNMWqGOWABYNQt4Yls/)

[image: required inputs]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Don't give the same name to all your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have unique names for each input.

change

```
 <input type="text" name="options" ngModel required>
```

to:

```
   <input type="text" [name]="element" ngModel required>
```